# Removing an object in an array of objects in elasticsearch document using an unique parameter in that object

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a document in elasticsearch which is like this:

```json
{
  "_index": "user",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "20",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": "20",
    "gender": null,
    "uuid": "68de0b74-cdf6-4e21-a046-6876e569e4e3",
    "first_name": null,
    "last_name": null,
    "nick_name": null,
    "email": null,
    "country_code": "98",
    "mobile": "9xxx7",
    "password": null,
    "old_password": null,
    "birthdate": null,
    "email_verified_at": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "old_data": null,
    "devices": [
      {
        "updated_at": "2021-12-14T12:11:26.000000Z",
        "serial": "sr_31",
        "vendor": "folan",
        "created_at": "2021-12-14T12:11:26.000000Z",
        "model": "device_model",
        "id": 4,
        "device_app": {
          "device_id": 4,
          "updated_at": "2021-12-14T12:11:26.000000Z",
          "created_at": "2021-12-14T12:11:26.000000Z",
          "id": 4,
          "uuid": "f60f7df0-5cd6-11ec-b71d-bdfd039f50b3"
        },
        "uuid": "f60a2ae0-5cd6-11ec-81cb-0128d6059ef1"
      },
      {
        "updated_at": "2021-12-14T12:13:07.000000Z",
        "serial": "sr_32",
        "vendor": "folan",
        "created_at": "2021-12-14T12:13:07.000000Z",
        "model": "device_model",
        "id": 5,
        "device_app": {
          "device_id": 5,
          "updated_at": "2021-12-14T12:13:07.000000Z",
          "created_at": "2021-12-14T12:13:07.000000Z",
          "id": 5,
          "uuid": "32481b80-5cd7-11ec-ba02-c33a09f165eb"
        },
        "uuid": "3242f860-5cd7-11ec-9d54-c3339177d9bb"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, I've got a field named `devices` which is an array of objects. I want to delete its first element not by selecting the index number of the array but with the content of the array, meaning that **I want to give the script the `serial` field (which is unique for each device) and delete the whole object of the corresponding object.

Let's say, I want some input to be `sr_31` and the output would be something like this (only the object containgin `sr_31` is omitted):

```json
{
  "_index": "user",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "20",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": "20",
    "gender": null,
    "uuid": "68de0b74-cdf6-4e21-a046-6876e569e4e3",
    "first_name": null,
    "last_name": null,
    "nick_name": null,
    "email": null,
    "country_code": "98",
    "mobile": "9xxx7",
    "password": null,
    "old_password": null,
    "birthdate": null,
    "email_verified_at": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "old_data": null,
    "devices": [
      {
        "updated_at": "2021-12-14T12:13:07.000000Z",
        "serial": "sr_32",
        "vendor": "folan",
        "created_at": "2021-12-14T12:13:07.000000Z",
        "model": "device_model",
        "id": 5,
        "device_app": {
          "device_id": 5,
          "updated_at": "2021-12-14T12:13:07.000000Z",
          "created_at": "2021-12-14T12:13:07.000000Z",
          "id": 5,
          "uuid": "32481b80-5cd7-11ec-ba02-c33a09f165eb"
        },
        "uuid": "3242f860-5cd7-11ec-9d54-c3339177d9bb"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have read [the document for updating a doc already](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html), but there seems no example for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is like this:

```
POST index/_doc/20/_update
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "ctx._source.devices.removeIf(device -> device.id == 'sr_31')"
  }
}
```

Comment: I've already seen this part of the document and it just searches for nested fields, the thing is that I want to remove the searched object.

Comment: @MajidAlaeinia What you need is [delete_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html)

Comment: `delete_by_query` deletes the whole document that matches that query, I just want to delete part of the document (update the document by deleting on matching nested object).

Comment: @MajidAlaeinia Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.